# Charts.js with vue not drawing charts after fetching data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

This is how json response looks like `[[61,57,34],[1,1,3]]` 
I want to use the first array for labels and the second for data.

If I set `labels and data` inside `app` manually it works though.

eg
`labels: ["q", "w", "e"]`
`data: [1, 5, 10]`

```
Vue.component('chart', {
  props: ['labels', 'data', 'type'],
  template: `
    <canvas style="width: 512px; height: 256px"></canvas>
  `,
  mounted: function () {
    new Chart(this.$el, {
      type: this.type,
      data: {
          labels: this.labels,
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: this.data,
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero:true
                  }
              }]
          }
        }
      })
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: "test",
    labels: [],
    data: []
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      this.$http.get('/admin/fetch_data').then(res => {
        this.labels = res.body[0];
        this.data = res.body[1];
      })
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }
});
```

component on page

```
<div id="app">
  {{message}}
  <chart :labels="labels" :data="data" type="bar"></chart>
</div>
```

The data seems to be loaded but there're no chart bars on page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your data is not yet fetched as you are performing an async task to fetch your data. By that time the component's mounted hook is called with empty props as the data you are passing as props is not yet loaded.

So do it like this:

```
Vue.component('chart', {
  props: ['labels', 'data', 'type' 'loaded'],
  template: `
    <canvas style="width: 512px; height: 256px"></canvas>
  `,
  watch:{
      loaded(isLoaded){
          if(isLoaded){
              this.drawChart();
          }
      }
  },
  methods:{
      drawChart: function () {
        new Chart(this.$el, {
          type: this.type,
          data: {
              labels: this.labels,
              datasets: [{
                  label: '# of Votes',
                  data: this.data,
                  borderWidth: 1
              }]
          },
          options: {
              scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                          beginAtZero:true
                      }
                  }]
              }
            }
          }) 
    }
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: "test",
    labels: [],
    data: [],
    loaded: false
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      this.$http.get('/admin/fetch_data').then(res => {
        this.labels = res.body[0];
        this.data = res.body[1];
        this.loaded = true;
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchData()
  }
});
```

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  {{message}}
  <chart :labels="labels" :data="data" :loaded="loaded" type="bar"></chart>
</div>
```

- add a property `loaded` set to false in your root vue instance and pass it as a prop
- change the `loaded` to `true` in the success callback of the promise returned by your `ths.$http.get()` request
- setup a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) in your `chart` component watching over this `loaded` prop
- invoke the `drawChart` method when the `loaded` prop`changes to`true`